# Similar matrix and eigenbasis

Tags: matrices

Would 2 matrices be similar matrices if they have two different eigenbasis?
Or when will two matrices are not similar if they have the same eigenvalues,  geometric/algebric mutiplicities, and rk(A-nI)=rk(B-nI) (n is eigenvalue).

Answer (score 2):

There *is* a criterion for two matrices to be similar: it is based on the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID.

Namely, if $A$ is the matrix, in some basis,  of an endomorphism $f$ of a finite dimensional vector space $E$ over a field $k$, you can make $E$ a $k[x]$-module through:
$$x\cdot u = f(u). $$
Let $\chi_A(x)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A$ (or $f$). By Cayley-Hamilton, $\chi_A(A)=0$, so that $\chi_A(x)\cdot u=0$ for any $u\in E$. This means $E$ is a *torsion* finitely generated module, and for such modules we know  there exists a sequence of polynomials $f_1, \dots, f_r$ such that $f_i\mid f_{i+1}$ $(i=1, \dots,r-1)$ and:
$$E\simeq k[x]/(f_1)\times\dotsm\times k[x]/(f_r)$$
These polynomials are the same for two matrices $A$, $B\,$ if and only $A$ and $B$ are similar, whence their name of *similarity invariants*.